# How can I boost a query based on a number in Solr

Tags: solr

How can I boost a query based on a integer field.

For example I have a field called highlight which can have the values 0, 10 or 20.

I would like to boost my search where the documents with the highlight value 20 appear before the 10 and 0.

My query is select/?q=Ford+Fiesta+Preto&defType=edismax&qf=brand+model+color^2&bq=highlight:10

Comment: Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents which could apply to your situation

Answer (score 1):

Use a [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) as part of your query.

Solr can parse function queries in the following syntax.

Some examples...

**# simple boosts by popularity**

```
defType=lucene&df=text&q=%2Bsupervillians+_val_:"popularity"
  defType=dismax&qf=text&q=supervillians&bf=popularity
  q={!boost b=popularity}text:supervillians
```

**# boosts based on complex functions of the popularity field**

```
defType=lucene&q=%2Bsupervillians+_val_:"sqrt(popularity)"
  defType=dismax&qf=text&q=supervillians&bf=sqrt(popularity)
  q={!boost b=sqrt(popularity)}text:supervillians
```